# jquery change or toggle images when clicked

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

I'm trying to do a 'when image1 is clicked, show image2, when image2 is clicked, show image3, when image3 is clicked, show image1...' thing.

It works for 2 images - image1 goes to 2 and image2 goes to 1 and so on, but when a 3rd image is introduced it gets messed up. My code is:

```
 <img id ="rotate_images" src="img1_on.png"/>

<script>

$('#rotate_images').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img1_on.png')
            ? 'img2_on.png'
            : 'img1_on.png';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img2_on.png')
            ? 'img3_on.png'
            : 'img2_on.png';
         $(this).attr('src', src);

     }

});
```

I sort of know why it's happening - image1 goes to image3, because it skips the first block of code, and image3 goes to image2, for the same reason but...is there something I could add in to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
<img id ="rotate_images" src="img1_on.png"/>

<script>
$('#rotate_images').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'img1_on.png') src = 'img2_on.png';
        if (origsrc == 'img2_on.png') src = 'img3_on.png';
        if (origsrc == 'img3_on.png') src = 'img1_on.png';
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris would appreciate this being marked as the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use `if` and `else if`. It only checks the second condition if the first was false, and goes into the `else` if neither condition was true.

```
$('#rotate_images').on({
    'click': function() {
         var newSrc,
             src = $(this).attr('src');
         if (src === 'img1_on.png') {
             newSrc = 'img2_on.png';
         } else if (src === 'img2_on.png') {
             newSrc = 'img3_on.png';
         } else {
             newSrc = 'img1_on.png';
         }
         $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
     }
});
```

However, if you want a more scalable solution, you can make a general algorithm that uses an array:

```
var imageSrcs = ['img1_on.png', 'img2_on.png', 'img3_on.png'];

$('#rotate_images').on({
    'click': function() {
         // find index of src within the array
         var index = imageSrcs.indexOf($(this).attr('src'));
         if (index < 0 || index == (imageSrcs.length - 1)) {
             // reset to first image
             index = 0;
         } else {
             // go to next image
             index++;
         }
         $(this).attr('src', imageSrcs[index]);
     }
});
```